# ¿Se pueden usar adjetivos como adverbios?

Tags: adjetivos, adverbios

Hay algo que me ha molestado desde que empecé a aprender español. He notado que a veces los adjetivos pueden usarse como adverbios. El ejemplo más prominente de este fenómeno es el uso de “junto” en esta manera. Cuando decimos “trabajaremos juntos,” no hay un sustantivo que el adjetivo “juntos” modifica, pero aún concuerda con el sujeto implícito de “nosotros.” Así, es definitivamente un adjetivo, pero aquí es definitivamente usado como adverbio.

Similarmente, en *El jorobado de Notre Dame* (la película de Disney), uno de los personajes dice “Beata María, tú sabes que hombre recto soy, que **orgulloso lucho** contra el mal" ("Beata Maria, you know that I am a righteous man, that I **fight proudly** against evil"). Me parece que debe ser "orgullosamente lucho."

¿Puede alguien explicarme este uso de adjetivos como adverbios?

(Si contesta esta pregunta e identifica un error, por favor, no dude en decirme *como un comentario*.)

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista es preferible decir _Si contesta esta pregunta..._. La palabra "cuestión" está bien usada, pero su significado se acerca más a "matter" o "issue" que a "question".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay al menos tres casos en los que un adjetivo "acompaña" a un verbo:

- **Adjetivo como [complemento predicativo subjetivo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_predicativo)**: El adjetivo actúa al mismo tiempo sobre el verbo y sobre un sustantivo con el que concuerda en género y número. Por ejemplo,  *María volvió cansada*. En este caso, "cansada" cumple la función gramatical de **adjetivo**. (De este tipo son las oraciones que indicas: *Yo lucho orgulloso* y *nosotros trabajaremos juntos*)
- **Adjetivo como [atributo o predicado nominal](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atributo_%28gram%C3%A1tica%29)**: En estos casos el adjetivo muestra una cualidad del sustantivo por medio de un verbo "copulativo", normalmente el verbo **ser**. Por ejemplo: *Sus ojos son hermosos*. En este caso, "hermosos" cumple la función gramatical de **adjetivo**.
- **[Adverbios adjetivales](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Adverbios%20adjetivales%20o%20cortos.htm)**: Adjetivos que indican una cualidad, pero no del sustantivo sino de la acción. Entonces, al tratarse de palabras que modifican al verbo, son **invariables** y se inmovilizan en la primera persona singular masculina. Por ejemplo *Ellas corren rápido*. En este caso "rápido" cumple la función gramatical de **adverbio**. En muchos casos se pueden formar quitando la terminación *-mente* a un adverbio de modo (*rápidamente* pasa a *rápido*). Pero hay casos en los que no se puede explicar de esa manera (p.ej. *cocina sabroso* no deriva de *sabrosamente*).

Todos estos casos son frecuentes. Los hablantes nativos no consideramos que se esté rompiendo una regla, al contrario, son procedimientos sintácticos disponibles.

Comment: Es interesante porque en el asturiano, se puede adverbializar un adjetivo bien con la forma femenina más *-mente* bien con la forma neutra. Ya que en el castellano las formas masculina y neutra coinciden en *-o*, pregúntome si el uso vendrá de algo parecido. En otros casos, puede ser elipsis: *Viajo feliz* puede ser más bien *hago un viaje, y en él, estoy feliz* en vez de *viajo en una manera feliz* que significa *viejo felizmente* sin ambigüedad.

Comment: @guifa: Espero que no pienses que estoy siendo grosero, ¿pero es la forma “pregúntome” correcta? ¿No debe ser “me pregunto”? El verbo “pregunto” es un verbo principal, ¿no?

Comment: @aprendedor está permitido colocar el pronombre después del verbo bajo ciertas condiciones (cuántas más se cumple, más se lo espera): al principio de una frase o después de una pausa, en registros muy altos, verbos con el se impersonal, con tono arcaizante y en ciertos dialectos. Pero no lo recomiendo a extranjeros a menos que tengan interés en uno de esos dialectos o el castellano áurico/muy formal, porque está sujeto a algunas otras reglas y restricciones

Answer (score 3):

Creo que casi contestas tú mismo a tu pregunta con este ejemplo

> [...]  que orgulloso lucho contra el mal

cuando dices

> Me parece que debe ser "orgullosa**mente** lucho."

Como bien sabes los adverbios definen a adjetivos, verbos u otros adverbios y sí, "orgulloso" es adjetivo y "orgullosamente" es adverbio. Se pueden formar adverbios a partir de un adjetivo añadiendo el sufijo *mente*. Cuando usamos dos adverbios terminados en "mente" seguidos sólo usamos el sufijo al final del último adjetivo:

> Lo explicó clara y eficazmente (no claramente y eficazmente)
>
> Lo terminó limpia y rápidamente.
>
> Aprendió rápida, cómoda y eficazmente a programar con ese libro.

Hay muchas otras excepciones en que el adjetivo puede funcionar como adverbio, de manera similar a cómo hemos quitado el sufijo *mente* en el ejemplo anterior:

> Se marchó rápido de allí (Se marchó *rápidamente* de allí)
>
> Lucho orgulloso contra el mal (Lucho de manera orgullosa / orgullosamente)
>
> Trabajaremos juntos (trabajaremos **con**junta**mente**)

Este último tenía un poco de truco, porque añade también un prefijo al formar el adverbio.

No siempre se puede usar el adjetivo como adverbio, y cuando se hace a veces conduce a confusión por la ambigüedad

> Preparó el coche rápido para su viaje

Quiere esto decir que preparó el coche *rápidamente*? O que tenía varios coches (uno "lento" y otro "rápido") y preparó el rápido para el viaje?

El único ejemplo que me venía ahora a la cabeza es el de rápido/rápidamente. Si encuentro una lista de casos en los que el adjetivo puede funcionar como adverbio actualizaré este post. Pero básicamente, puede hacerse y se hace sobre todo para no recargar el uso de "mente" en la construcción de esos adverbios.

Answer (score 0):

*Lucho orgulloso contra el mal.
Trabajaremos juntos.*
En ambos casos están actuando como adjetivos *orgullosos* y *juntos*, no como adverbios. Pues en el caso de los adverbios estos no se adecuan en género o número a la palabra que acompañan. En el primer caso de haber sido alguien del género femenino quien pronunciase la oración esta pasaría a ser:
*Lucho orgullosa contra el mal.*
O, en caso de ser varias personas sería:
*Luchamos orgullosos contra el mal.*
O *Luchamos orgullosas contra el mal*, en caso de ser varias mujeres.
Lo mismo en la segunda oración podría darse el mismo caso que en el último ejemplo, siendo:
*Trabajaremos juntas.*
En este segundo caso lo que no se daría es que el adjetivo llegara a ser singular, en cualquiera de los géneros.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de descubrir este foro de consulta. Estoy escribiendo un texto personal, y quisiera puedan opinar, y eventualmente corregir la siguiente frase (es acerca del uso de adjetivos en lugar de adverbios)

Apenas he comenzado a entender, cada vez más **claro**, que hay una gigantesca realidad de vida, de verdor espiritual, de aguas que nunca cesan, y satisfacen más que cualquier fuente en este mundo.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenida a Spanish.SE! En este sitio, damos importancia a que las respuestas realmente respondan a la pregunta correspondiente. Por favor, no escribas una respuesta para hacer otra pregunta. Si tienes una nueva duda, puedes plantearla como una [nueva pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Hola, Carmen, bienvenida al sitio. Fíjate que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, si vas a publicar una pregunta debes hacerla como tal, y no como respuesta a otra pregunta. Busca el botón "Ask Question" arriba del todo para plantear una nueva pregunta. Cuando plantees la pregunta, especificamente de forma muy clara cuál es tu duda y qué has investigado hasta ahora, para que podamos ayudarme lo mejor posible. Cuando lo hagas, por favor elimina esta respuesta y así dejaremos el sitio más ordenadito.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias!