# ¿Es "-mente" un agregado obligatorio para adverbios?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, adverbios

En mi país es común oír oraciones como: 
"*La niña camina veloz.*" o "*El perro corre rápido.*"

Yo creo que estos son gramaticalmente incorrectos y que deberían ser:
"*La niña camina veloz**mente**.*" o "*El perro corre rápid**amente**.*"

Pero es tan frecuente el uso de las primeras oraciones que no estoy realmente  seguro.

¿Las primeras oraciones son correctas? ¿O son erróneas y es simplemente un regionalismo?

Según la respuesta a otra pregunta sobre "[El uso de adjetivos como adverbios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12716/5481)", creo entender que estos son **adverbios adjetivales** y por lo tanto ambas, **tanto** las primeras **como** las segundas oraciones están correctas.

Si este es el caso, ¿cómo saber cuándo agregar "-mente" a un adjetivo para que actúe como adverbio? O ¿es inconsecuente, y simplemente cuestión de preferencia personal?

Answer (score 4):

Que sepa, no debe ser un regionalismo.  Es algo que se encuentra en las lenguas ibéricas (y posiblemente en otras romances pero es que no conozco bien la gramática de ellas).

En la *Nueva Gramática*, la ASALE habla de la derivación adverbial en el latín:

> El latín […] creó, además, adverbios mediante la recategorización de adjetivos de género neutro en acusativo (*multum* 'mucho' o *facĭle* 'fácilmente') o ablativo (*merĭto* 'con razón', 'merecidamente'; *raro* 'raramente').
>
> **30.3b** El latín formaba sistemáticamente adverbios a partir de adjetivos mediate la adición de los sufijos *-ĕ* […] y -ter […] También se valía de la recategorización de adjetivos de género neutro en acusativo (*multum* 'mucho' o *facĭle* 'fácilmente') o ablativo (*raro* 'raramente'). El proceso general de adverbialización de adjetivos se mantuvo, con intensidad variable, en todas las lenguas románicas. La pauta era particularmente productiva en el español antiguo, en el que se extendía a un gran número de adjetivos.
>
> > Ruiseñores e gallos que son más fermosetas / porque cantan **hermoso**, estas son más caretas (*Alexandre); EL quatorzeno viçio es fablar **escuro** de palabras sufisticadas (*Cancionero Íxar*); En fin de razones, fablando cortés, / yo mucho querría sabe si assí es (Baena, *Cancionero*); Fazía muy **desaguisado** dexar el moço, que era tierno et non podría sofrir lazeria (Juan Manuel, *Lucanor*); Como yo creo, dezía **aguisado** (*Alexandre*).

Siendo un resto del latín significaría que lo podríamos esperar encontrarlo en todos los dialectos del español.  Y de hecho, así es:<sup>2</sup>

> **30.3c** En la actualidad los adverbios se documentan tanto en el español europeo como en el americano, pero poseen más vitalidad en este último. […]

Las restricciones son interesantes.  En principio, no todos los adjetivos se pueden usar como adverbios (ni con *-mente*), y de los que admiten adverbialización, no todos se pueden usar sin *-mente*.  La formación con *-mente* es obligatorio cuando el adverbio modifica adjetivos o participios, es decir, suelen modificar el verbo.

De hecho, la conexión con el verbo puede ser tanto que cuando se usa el adverbio adjetival se puede interpretar como un predicado complejo:

> **30.3e** […] Se ha observado que muchos de ellos [adverbios adjetivals] forman con el verbo un **predicado complejo** que constituye casi una locución verbal: *pisar firme, irle a uno bonito, trabajar duro, hablar claro, jugar limpio* (o *sucio*), etc.  En el lenguaje deportivo son frecuentes *chutar fuerte*, *disparar raso*, *sacar alto*, *dominar fácil*, entre otras expresiones similares, no todas igualmente empleadas en todas las áreas hispanohablantes.

En muchos de los casos descritos en 30.3e, el uso del adverbio adjetival ya no se permite una vez que el adverbio se aleja del verbo: uno puede *chutar fuerte el balón* pero más difícilmente llegaría a decir *chutar el balón fuerte*.  No obstante, hay algunos que permite separación (y los cuantificadores no cuentan como alejamiento: *chutar muy fuerte*).

Fuera de estas expresiones, hay ciertas tendencias en los adjetivos que admiten adverbialización sin *-mente*.  Por ejemplo, los adjetivos «que expresan similitud y diferencia* (§ 30.3l) y los «que expresan evaluación, generalmente positiva, de la manera de actuar» (§ 30.3m).  No obstante los con sentido negativo son menos frecuentes, aunque posibles sobre todo con *feo*, *fatal* y *pésimo* (§ 30.3n).  Hay también otros que se utilizan mucho o incluso principalmente en respuestas y exclamaciones (*natural, seguro, evidente, claro*).

Entonces, respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta, **se podría decir que siempre se puede usar *-mente*** (si es que tal adjetivo se deja convertirse en adverbio).  **La única restricción sería si**, por el uso tras el tiempo, **la forma con y sin *-mente* hubiese llegado a distinguirse** pues entonces hay que elegir según significado que puede variar mucho según región (por ejemplo, compárese la diferencia entre *hablar honroso de alguien* y *hablar honrosamente de alguien* con la ambigüedad de *hablar bien de alguien*)

---

<sup>1. En el asturiano, por ejemplo, todavía se puede alternar entre las formas con *-mente* y con el neutro *-o* cuando modifica al verbo, sin muchas restricciones (G.Ll.A.3.ª: «**XIV.3** Los axetivos puen adautase a categoría alverbial per aciu de dos procedimientos. En primer llugar, cola inmovilización morfemática, fixando la terminación propia del neutru: *préstame **poco** esa película, convién filar **fino**, vieno **primero** Beatriz, miróme torcío, trabaya mui **curioso**, corríen **rápido**, colaron **escapao**, espresáronse **claro**, cantaben **sele**, falái **prudente**, yá fala **regular** l'inglés.*.  Dice la G.B.A. (provisional) «**13.1.1.b** Los adverbios adchectivals tienen la forma d'o masculino singular d'uun adchectivo calificativo u participio, como *claro* (*charra claro*) u *baixo* (*ixes avions volan baixo*).  Son, por un regular, adverbios de manera y resultan d'a recategorización d'ixes adchectivos.  Chunto a l'adverbio *bien* fan la clase d'os denominaus *adverbios curtos*.  **13.1.1.c** Buena cosa d'adverbios quantitativos tienen la misma forma que los quantificadors que modifican un substantivo. Quan lo quantificador tien flexión de chenero y numero, iste apareix immobilizau en masculino singular, como *muito, pro, desmasiato*, etc. *Estianyo los míos alumnos han estudiau pro*».  Aunque no lo dice, me parece que es, como en castellano y portugués, una clase cerrada que no admite nuevos vocablos.</sup>

<sup>2. Curiosamente, el portugués tiene una distribución parecida.  Los hablantes brasileños tienden a usar el *adjetivo adverbializado*, como se llama en portugués, más que los hablantes europeos; no encontré referencia sobre el portugués africano o asiático).</sup>