# Can 'magnánimo' be used as an adverb?

Tags: adverbios

I saw this sentence in Jorge Luis Borges' book "El Aleph":

> La fiebre y la magia consumieron a muchos hombres que codiciaban **magnánimos** el acero.

It seems to me 'magnánimos' is being used as an adverb. Is this proper? Or is this some Argentine quirk? Shouldn't it be 'magnánimamente'?

Comment: Esta pregunta: "[El uso de adjetivos como adverbios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12709/5481)" explica los adjetivos adverbiales: "Adjetivos que indican una cualidad, pero no del sustantivo sino de la acción." Entiendo que lo esperado sería "hombres que codiciaban **magnánimamente** el acero". Las respuestas de la pregunta enlazada discuten ese uso de "magnánimo" (adj.) en lugar de "magnánimamente" (adv.). Mira también [¿Es “-mente” un agregado obligatorio para adverbios?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20667/5481)

Comment: "magnánimos" is not a way of coveting for anything. It describes, within the predicate, a **quality of the subject** as they covet for something. I liked Rodrigo's answer in the linked question, but I don't know if the question posed by @chickenhead is properly or clearly answered this way.