# Translation Golf XXXIV - Rick and Morty

Tags: translation-golf

> Y el ganador is: Charlie!

Esta ronda, la traducción proviene de la ultima temporada de Rick and Morty ([S3E8 clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJcgeN4CfwI)):

> Morty, I need darkness to prime these optical inductors.
> Hit the leftmost light switch by the door for me. The left. Okay,
> lights on. So, did I just hear three distinct light switch clicks?
>
> W-W-What do you mean?
>
> I feel like the three sounds I heard could be
> explained by an initial erroneous flipping of a switch on the right
> followed by a hasty, corrective flipping of the requested switch. Then
> during the resultant darkness and silence, a third, shameful
> unflipping of the initially flipped switch. Is my assessment accurate?
>
> Yeah, that's that's basically how how it all shaked out. I'm sorry.
>
> Ugh... Grab a shovel.

<sub>510 caracteres</sub>

Un ejemplo de traducción a continuación, aunque el ganador necesitará pensar y hacer un esfuerzo para encontrar palabras que no sean los binomios del inglés si quiere superar a los demás concursantes:

> Morty, necesito oscuridad completo para cebar estos tres inductores ópticos.
>  Corte el interruptor de luz a la izquierda cerca de la puerta por mí. El que
>  está a la izquierda. Bueno, prende la luz. ¿Entonces, he oído tres chasquidos  distintas del interruptor?
>  Qué quire decir?
>  Me parece que los tres sonidos que escuché puede ser explicado por un erróneo  conmutación del interruptor a la derecha seguido por otro ajetreado
>  apagamiento de la luz pedida. Luego, durante la oscuridad resultante y
>  silencio, un tercero, vergonzoso conmutación del primero interruptor cortado.  Es mi evaluación acertada?
>  Si, asi es en esencia como todo resultó. Lo siento.
>  Ugh. Bien, Vamanos.
>  Qué?
>  Vamanos. Coja una pala.

<sub>561 caracteres</sub>

Iba a usar el texto de [**este clip**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU1fLmpZtZs) pero no hay bastantes palabras interesantes como para incentivar la creatividad. En caso de empate, el ganador será decidido por traducir este:

> Man, that guy is the redgren grumbholdt of pretending he knows what's
> going on. [Rick and Summer laugh.] Oh, you agree, huh? It's funny.
> You like that redgren grumbholdt reference? Yeah. Well, guess what? I
> made him up. You really are your father's children. Think for
> yourselves. Don't be sheep.

El ejemplo:

> ¡Caramba! Este tipo es el regren grumbholdt de fingiendo que está al corriente. Vaya, están de acuerdo, sí? Es divertido. Les gustan esta referencia a redgren grumbholdt. Adivinan qué?  Me lo inventé. De verdad están los hijos de su padre. Piensan por si mismos. No sean ovejas.

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters?
Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: @walen uh oh. De verdad equivoqué en contar días y un nuevo ronda ya ha empezado. Estamos en un lio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### <strike>242</strike> 195 caracteres

> —Morty, los inductores ópticos se preparan a oscuras. Dale a la luz, al de la [zoca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cS7RuWc), junto al [uzo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bDvyQXy). Vale, ¡luces! ¿He oído tres [clics](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9SZ4Kat)?
>   —¿Qué?
>   —Le diste al de la diestra, luego con [apuro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3LmP7tP) al bueno, y ya sin luz de nuevo al primero. ¿Es así?
>   —Básicamente sí, perdón.
>   —¡A cavar!

Aclaraciones:

- El DPD [certifica](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=clic) que el plural de *clic* es *clics*.
- Descubro que *zoca* significa "mano izquierda", luego "al de la zoca" se puede interpretar como "el que está a mano izquierda" o "al alcance de la mano izquierda". Por coherencia uso "diestra" más adelante, aunque tiene las mismas letras que "derecha".
- Entiendo que tienen que coger las palas para cavar y enterrar algo, así que uso el verbo "cavar" que hace la frase más corta.

Comment: ¿Al de la zoca junto al uzo? Jajaja. Encuentras cada palabra, menuda frase más rara.

Comment: Viendo que **zoca** viene de **zoquete**, no parece una palabra políticamente correcta, pero muy en la línea de Rick

Answer (score 4):

#### 210

> —Morty, no puedo [cebar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=84ilYVT#3XlxkeC) estos inductores ópticos si hay luz. [Dale](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35#M3owE4j) al [mando](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OA3ulOZ#ANil304) izquierdo junto a la puerta. Izquierdo. Ya, luz. ¿Acaso oí 3 [clics](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9SZ4Kat) distintos?
> —¿Q-que [insinúas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LkwZc6M)?
> —[Diste](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35#M3owE4j) al derecho, luego [rápido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V9EXpqS) al [bueno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6EawoZ6#JxPSXsA) y luego [vil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bobcqY3) al [primo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UBQk8bX). ¿[Sí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmQKxT2)?
> —Sí, m-[más o menos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ). [Perdón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SYbMpnJ#GgfhFUv).
> —[Uf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zBgLN)... Coge una pala.

Sobre el uso de *rápido* y *vil*: [¿Se pueden usar adjetivos como adverbios?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/se-pueden-usar-adjetivos-como-adverbios)

Comment: Por qué usó la palabra diste? Esto no cabe aquí.

Comment: Claro. Olvidė decir es dijiste.

Comment: Vilmente requiere explicación por favor.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no puedo aceptar de manera vil por vergonzoso. Necesita otra palabra mas leal al original sentido. Corrígeme si disiente.

Comment: Es un tramo pero ok.