# ¿Es correcto el uso del adjetivo en lugar del adverbio?

Tags: adjetivos, adverbios

Estoy escribiendo un texto personal, y quisiera su opinión para, en su caso, corregir la siguiente frase (es acerca del uso de adjetivos en lugar de adverbios).

La oración está a continuación. La palabra que tengo en duda es "claro": ¿se acepta su uso aquí en lugar de "claramente"?

> *Apenas he comenzado a entender, cada vez más **claro**, que hay una gigantesca realidad de vida, de verdor espiritual, de aguas que nunca cesan, y satisfacen más que cualquier fuente en este mundo.*

Comment: Es la forma escueta del adverbio.

Comment: [¿Se pueden usar adjetivos como adverbios?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12709/6915)

Answer (score 6):

Del mismo modo que *rápido*, la palabra *claro* también puede usarse como adverbio, es decir, como sinónimo de *claramente*. Esto está recogido en la acepción 32 (!) de *[claro](https://dle.rae.es/claro)*:

> **32.** adv. claramente. *Hablaban claro*.

La oración en la pregunta es por tanto correcta.